# Java: Automatic cookie handling in HttpClient?

Tags: java, apache, httpclient

In [Java HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/index.html) feature list it says:

> Automatic Cookie handling for reading
>   Set-Cookie: headers from the server
>   and sending them back out in a Cookie:
>   header when appropriate.

But I can't figure out how to use this feature. I just need to open a web page, let it set all the cookies, then refresh the same page with received cookies.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I kept getting errors back from the server saying my client didn't support cookies and I should turn them on.  The following line stopped those errors.  Hope this works for you.

```
httpClient.setCookieStore(new BasicCookieStore());
```